# Macbook Snowleoaprd Model Identifier:MacBook1,1 python error

Tags: python, macos, gcc, wine

Hi i update python with the latest version Python 3.3.2 and i too update gcc with the latest version so: 
Python 3.3.2 (default, Nov 19 2013, 05:46:40)
[GCC 4.8.2] on darwin
But there is something falling. I try install python module libxslt and when i start compile libxslt and it check for python it give this error:

```
checking for perl... perl
checking for python... /usr/local/bin/python
PYTHON is pointing at /usr/local/bin/python
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print sys.version[0:3]
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Found Python version
  File "<string>", line 1
    try : import libxml2 ; print 1
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Warning: Missing libxml2-python
checking for libgcrypt-config... /usr/local/bin/libgcrypt-config
Crypto extensions will be available.
Enabling debugger
checking for libxml libraries >= 2.6.27... 2.7.3 found
checking whether shared libraries will be built (required for plugins)... yes
checking libxml2 module support... yes
```

I just want to compile the wine 1-6-1.

Updates: wine 1-6-1 is complaining for winemac.drv and winehq.com or .org says there need to be added in ./configure --disable-winemac.drv so i put ./configure --disable-winemac.drv and this command don't exist.

Now i start to compile things: so i need to install mesa to get opengl driver, but mesa don't compile becouse complain for another driver libxml2-python where i can get i search the internet and didn't find nothing so i find this driver libxml2-2.9.1 and i try to compile too i try i python directory python setup.py install and it give error:

> jack-MacBook:python root# python setup.py   File "setup.py", line 70
>       break;
>            ^ TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation jack-MacBook:python root# python setup.py install   File
>   "setup.py", line 70
>       break;
>            ^ TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: print in Python 3 is formatted as a function call.  Parentheses are required.  So, e.g., print(sys.version[0:3]).  Wherever this bad print is coming from, it's Python 2 code.  You need to figure out why you're using Python 2 code instead of Python 3 code.

Comment: How and where ? How can i remove all python 2 version, i'm not programmer.

Comment: Shit you programmer need to put download links where peoples can get programs. Now i need to install autoreconf: running: aclocal 
configure.ac:7: error: must install xorg-macros 1.3 or later before running autoconf/autogen and i can't find it for macosx neither for snowleopard

Comment: SHAME ON YOU ALL programers men and ALL programers women. autoconf
aclocal.m4:14: error: this file was generated for autoconf 2.61.
You have another version of autoconf.  If you want to use that,
you should regenerate the build system entirely.
aclocal.m4:14: the top level
autom4te: /usr/local/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 63
TO ALL WHITE HUMANKIND. WE ARE FREE.